# retrieving text field value using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to retrieve textfield value using javascript. suppose i have a code like:

```
 <input type='text' name='txt'>
```

And I want to retrieve it using javascript. I call a function when a button is clicked:

```
<input type='button' onclick='retrieve(txt)'>
```

What coding will the retrieve function consist of?

Answer (score 12):

You can do this:

**Markup:**

```
<input type="text" name="txt" id="txt"/>
<input type="button" onclick="retrieve('txt');"/>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function retrieve(id) {
    var txtbox = document.getElementById(id);
    var value = txtbox.value;
}
```

Comment: Also change `name='txt'` to `id='txt'` (or add it) on the text input.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have an input on your page with an id of `input1`, like this:

```
<input type="text" id="input1" />
```

You first need to get the element, and if you know the Id, you can use `document.getElementById('input1')`. Then, just call `.value` to get the value of the input box:

```
var value = document.getElementById('input1').value;
```

**Update**

Based on your markup, I would suggest specifying an `id` for your text box. Incase you don't have control over the markup, you can use [document.getElementsByName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByName), like so:

```
var value = document.getElementsByName('txt')[0].value;
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the way is already explained by **Andrew Hare**.

You can also do it by entering the value in the textbox and getting a prompt box with entered message when a user click the button.

Let's say, you have a textbox and a input button

```
<input type="text" name="myText" size="20" />
<input type="button" value="Alert Text" onclick="retrieve()" />
```

The function for `retrieve()`

```
function retrieve()
{
     var text = document.simpleForm.myText.value;
     alert(text);
}
```