# Get textbox value in Javascript (single/multiple fields)

Tags: javascript, html

I have a field in my page named as "myField"
Now this is dynamic So there are 2 cases i.e. it can be just 1 field as;

```
<input type="text" name="myField" />
```

OR there can be 2 fields as below;

```
<input type="text" name="myField" />
<input type="hidden" name="myField" />
```

I use the following code to access the value in JS;

```
document.forms[0].myField[0].value
```

However, this does not work if there is only 1 field (as in the first case)

How do I write dynamic JS code to handle the same?
It should be cross browser compatible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [retrieving text field value using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074059/retrieving-text-field-value-using-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, because in the first case you should use `document.forms[0].myField.value`.

I'd suggest to retrieve elements with [`getElementsByName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByName) method:

```
var val = document.getElementsByName("myField")[0].value;
```

Comment: is this cross browser compatible ?

Comment: @testndtv Of course. This is a native JavaScript method for DOM manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

better way is to give a unique ID to each element and then get it with

```
document.getElementById(id).value
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [JQuery](http://jquery.com), and [here's](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_val.asp) some information on how to get the value out.

Answer (score 0):

provided there is at least one element name "myField"

```
var count = document.forms[0].myField.length;
for(var i=0; i < count; i++){
    // do something with document.forms[0].myField[i].value
    console.log(document.forms[0].myField[i].value);
}
```

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/HtrrT/